# Issue printing api weather data too a html page

Tags: html, typescript, api, ionic-framework, weather-api

I am trying too code a very basic Weather app that pulls data from this API https://openweathermap.org/api. When  I click the link too go from the home.html file too the weatherData.html nothing is showing up and I cant seem too pinpoint the issue within my code,any help would be appreciated.

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Weather Ireland
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title size="large">Weather Ireland</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <a class="button icon-right ion-plus-round" href="../weather-data/weather-data.page.html">weatherData</a>
</ion-content>
```

This is the code for the homepage.html which links too the weatherData.html file where the information from the API is supposed to be printed.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import {WeatherDataService} from '../weather-data.service'

import { WeatherDataPageRoutingModule } from './weather-data-routing.module';

import { WeatherDataPage } from './weather-data.page';



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    WeatherDataPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [WeatherDataPage]
})
export class WeatherDataPageModule {
  weather;

  constructor(private weatherdataservice: WeatherDataService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.weatherdataservice.getWeather().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.weather = data['weather'];
    }
    )
  }
}
```

This is the code for the data.html file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import {WeatherDataService} from '../weather-data.service'

import { WeatherDataPageRoutingModule } from './weather-data-routing.module';

import { WeatherDataPage } from './weather-data.page';



@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    WeatherDataPageRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [WeatherDataPage]
})
export class WeatherDataPageModule {
  weather;

  constructor(private weatherdataservice: WeatherDataService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.weatherdataservice.getWeather().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.weather = data['weather'];
    }
    )
  }
}
```

this is the code for  the data.module.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherDataService {

  APIKey = 'fec30507acb533f670080ab3174f226f';


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getWeather(){
  return this.httpClient.get('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={53.87}&lon={8.63}&appid={fec30507acb533f670080ab3174f226f}')
  }

}
```

this is the code for the data.services ts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From below code, seems like you wanted to redirect to some page though you have response from the api. Instead of link redirection, try to create new page and pass response.

```
    <ion-header [translucent]="true">
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
          Weather Ireland
        </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
      <ion-header collapse="condense">
        <ion-toolbar>
          <ion-title size="large">Weather Ireland</ion-title>
        </ion-toolbar>
      </ion-header>

      **<a class="button icon-right ion-plus-round" href="../weather-data/weather-data.page.html">weatherData</a>**

    </ion-content>
```

In WeatherDataPage try using NavController
declare, navCtrl: NavController in constructor and use this.navCtrl.push(component_name, {whetherData: this.weather});

And after navigating to new component page use, NavParams. Declare navParams: NavParams and use navParams.get("whetherData");

Comment: In the new file  am I using type script file or the module file

Comment: constructor(public navCtrl:NavController){}
    this.navCtrl.push(DataHolderPageModule),{WeatherDataPageModule:this.weather}; with this line of code im also getting an error " Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected."

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'weather-data/weather-data.page.html'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'weather-data/weather-data.page.html'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:4295)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:4259)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:29)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    these are some of the errors when I clicked inspect element in the browser

Comment: this.navCtrl.push(____),{WeatherDataPageModule:this.weather}; inside blank put name of your component for example, "WhetherDataPageComponent" (your new component page)